# How to replace target VM and NIC on Azure Load Balancer Inbound NAT Rule

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-network, azure-load-balancer

I have an existing Azure Frontend load balancer that has inbound NAT rules.  I want to change the target/destination of those NAT rules in mass to a new target server.

I currently have a script built that gets all the NAT rules from the LB and then iterates through them and attempts to ADD them to the NIC of the new server.  I have tried with and without REMOVING the NAT rule from the NIC of the old server.  Either way, the method returns false and no change is applied.

```
#Set Variables
#subscription ID
$subscription = "value"
#the name of the old NIC that has the LB rules
$OldNicName = "old_nic"
#the name of the NIC to be attached to the LB rules
$NewNicName = "new_nic"
#name of the loadbalancer
$lbname = "my_lb"

#Set Active Subscription
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscription

#Get the loadbalancer
$lb = Get-AzLoadBalancer -Name $lbname

#Get the old firewall interface/NIC
$OldNic = Get-AzNetworkInterface -Name $OldNicName

#Get the target firewall interface/NIC
$NewNic = Get-AzNetworkInterface -Name $NewNicName

#Attach NAT rules to the NIC
$lb.InboundNatRules | ForEach-Object -Process {$OldNic.IpConfigurations[0].LoadBalancerInboundNatRules.Remove($_); $NewNic.IpConfigurations[0].LoadBalancerInboundNatRules.Add($_)}

#Apply the configuration and reload the NIC
$OldNic | Set-AzNetworkInterface
$NewNic | Set-AzNetworkInterface
```

I want for each inbound NAT rule to now be associated to the new NIC/VM but at present both the Remove() and Add() functions above are returning FALSE.

Comment: I found a way to remove the NAT rules from the NIC, but only in AZ CLI, not Powershell.  After running these commands in AZ CLI the powershell script will work.  ``` az network nic ip-config inbound-nat-rule remove -g rs-group --nic-name nic_name -n ipconfig1 --inbound-nat-rule test-nat-rule-1 --lb-name test-lb```  However, you have to remove each rule one at a time, which defeats the purpose of a script.

Comment: How about instead of using the `Remove()` and `Add()` methods you just assign the values like `$OldNic.IpConfigurations[0].LoadBalancerInboundNatRules = $OldNic.IpConfigurations[0].LoadBalancerInboundNatRules |Where{$_ -notin $lb.InboundNatRules}` and `$NewNic.IpConfigurations[0].LoadBalancerInboundNatRules = $NewNic.IpConfigurations[0].LoadBalancerInboundNatRules + $lb.InboundNatRules`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your issue, you want to change the target/destination of those NAT rules in mass to a new target server. The NAT rules associated with the VM network interface and set in the interface IP configuration. So you need to use the two PowerShell command `Set-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig` and `Set-AzNetworkInterface` to achieve your purpose. The script like this:

```
# Set Variables
# subscription ID
$subscription = "value"
# the name of the old NIC that has the LB rules
$OldNicName = "old_nic"
# the name of the NIC to be attached to the LB rules
$NewNicName = "new_nic"
# name of the loadbalancer
$lbname = "my_lb"
# assume all the resources in the same group
$groupname = "group_name"

Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscription

# remove the NAT rules from the old NIC
$oldNic = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $groupname -Name $OldNicName
$list = @()       # this is a empty array
Set-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -Name ipconfig1 -NetworkInterface $oldNic -LoadBalancerInboundNatRule $list 
$oldNic | Set-AzNetworkInterface

# associate the NAT rules to the new NIC

$newNic = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $groupname -Name $NewNicName
$lb = Get-AzLoadBalancer -ResourceGroupName $groupname -Name $lbname
$NatRules = Get-AzLoadBalancerInboundNatRuleConfig -LoadBalancer $lb
Set-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -Name ipconfig1 -NetworkInterface $newNic -LoadBalancerInboundNatRule $NatRules
$newNic | Set-AzNetworkInterface
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this should work.  On vacation right now. Will update when I get back in the office.